# ubuntu automount: only mounting drives as root?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-server, automount

I'm sharing the /mount dir with smb so users on my network can access use drives added to my linux box. Users are able to read files but not write, modify or delete files or directories.

I'm using ubuntu 10.04 server edition with halevt installed for usb auto mounting. Afaik halevt is automounting the drives to /media/ but the drives are showing up as:

```
drwxrwxr-x 1 root root 20480 2010-12-29 20:40 disk
drwxrwxr-x 1 root root 24576 2010-12-21 17:20 Sparta
```

mount gives me:

```
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/disk type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,sync,allow_other,blksize=4096,default_permissions)
/dev/sdc1 on /media/Sparta type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,sync,allow_other,blksize=4096,default_permissions)
```

When I umount the drives, the folders /media/disk and /media/Sparta are both removed. I tried changing the permissions with chown to nobody:nogroup but it doesn't work (which I assume is because they are ntfs drives).